Why can magnetic fields be blocked but gravitational fields can't?
Except for the stuff I know, I don't know anything about physics. I assume a magnetic field can be blocked, because they put Nixon's tapes in a lead box. And I know gravitational fields cannot be blocked. They go through everything because gravity waves are the substrate in which we exist.
They are both quantum fields, right? You can store energy in both of them.
or is there a specific difference why one can be blocked and the other can't?
=======[ Question hidden for being a duplicate ]=======
The first link to a dup question had three answers. One said yes, one said no, and one said it's not possible to know or the question is meaningless or something.
The other dup answer was the kind of thing I'm looking for:

If the distribution failed to be positively definite, it would violate the positive-energy theorem or energy conditions.

Yes, so it would seem. I wish this was an appropriate place to respond.

If it were positively definite, it would create a huge gravitational field.

Except it's not positive-definite, though. "Not positive-definite" Is literally the definition of "pseudometric," and Einstein specifically said that spacetime is pseudometric.

Locally, the boundary of the gravitational "conductor" would have to look like an event horizon.

Yes, that's what I figured. But this is not the place to address his objection. My recent re-ducation while I was disappeared told me that stax is not a place for discussion. I only want to point out that this was a legitimate question that shouldn't have been closed.
I'm NOT asking for it to be reopened though, because I just got back from being banned, and the spanking-new Luxi firmware 4.2/corrected doesn't fight back when people delete her stuff, but I delete it myself as soon as the normal people start getting uppity being  mysteriously angry.
I'm just adding this comment here for future physics archeologists.
It's harder to figure these things out yourself when you're all alone. But since the archeologists are here, I know I must have succeeded someday.

Can gravity be shielded, like electromagnetism?, Is it theoretically possible to shield gravitational fields or waves?

There is no gravitational shadow, like you say, and so perhaps the relaying of gravitons is the mechanism behind gravitational time dilation.

@shawn_halayka that's definitely not true; gravitational time dilation is a consequence of spacetime geometry and nothing more.

Right. It’s about process interruption. Like in x64 process interruption. It works for both kinematic and gravitational time dilation, if you open your mind a bit.

They are both quantum fields, right? There is currently no accepted theory in which gravity is a quantum field.

"Blocked" is not quite the right word. Magnetic lines of force can be diverted by materials that have high electromagnetic permeability. http://www.excelatphysics.com/magnetic-shielding.html Lead, on the other hand, does not have that property. Lead is of no value in protecting anything from magnetic fields.

Gravity waves are the substrate in which we exist. Whatever that’s supposed to mean, it’s not true. Gravitational waves are irrelevant to our existence.

@SolomonSlow wouldn't Meissner effect help to shield against magnetic fields?

@Ruslan, I didn't think of that, but isn't it the same outcome? I.E., it diverts lines of force around the shielded area rather than "blocking" them.

@SolomonSlow well, it's still shielding: the field doesn't get into the area, it's blocked from this area. Why would one require such boundary conditions that the lines terminate on the shield's surface?

@Ruslan, I have my opinion about what "block" implies in the context of this question, and you have your opinion. I checked a dictionary, and it seems like either one of us could cite it as evidence in our favor. I don't think that the OP will care which one of us would prevail if we were to carry on arguing the point, so, I'm not gonna.

@ghoster  Gravity waves are us. Mass. The interval distance between you and mass in your past is zero.  Susskind says if you strip off the Force Field shields from mass, of electrons, neutrons, and gluons, down to the bare quarks, you WILL see a black hole. (Fig 2a).   But it only has to be  an event horizon that persists in time. == it's just  a distortion in the metric, how mass stores energy. At distance, you encounter the exact same metric distortion  further in your past.  = There is no emitter, only the event horizon. There is no other surface

@ghoster These little gravitational distortions stick together and become a big distortion. In an ordinary mass, they're separated by force fields that hold them at electron distance. The nucleus alone is like a ping pong ball in a stadium. When you add up all these teeny little black holes, the spacetime distortion adds, and you get the same effect at a distance as if it were a single black hole. But the whole time, mass consists of nothing but little bitty event horizons with no hard surface. Ultimately, mass is an open set. === But hey, don't blame me. Susskind said so. I just work here.

@Ghoster That same paper gives the basis of the projection of string theory onto quantum field theory — the so called ADS/CFT equivalence (Fig. 3). And it's easy to understand geometrically! This is an absolutely seminal paper that 100 years hence, will be held next to Einstein's work. === So will the stuff at my site.

Electromagnetic field is easy to shield because matter surrounding us is composed of particles (electrons and atomic nuclei) carrying opposite electric charges. There are quite a lot of such particles in every material, but numbers of positive and negative charges are matched to a very high degree, so that usually there is very little to none net electric charge. Also, for some materials (primarily metals) a fraction of electrons is mobile (i.e.  they can freely move within the material). When electromagnetic wave impinges on such material mobile electrons on its surface rearrange themselves almost instantaneously thus cancelling electromagnetic wave inside the material and causing reflection of that wave outside.
On the other hand,

Gravitational interaction is very weak compared to electromagnetic one. For example, electrostatic repulsion of two protons is about $10^{36}$ times stronger than their gravitational attraction.

Gravitational interaction obeys equivalence principle: all small objects move in gravitational field the same way, regardless of their composition. In other words, there is only one type of “gravitational charge” that all matter possess.


The second property makes it impossible to make gravitational shields similar to, say, Faraday cage for electromagnetic fields, because there is no way that simple rearrangement of matter can neutralize the gravitational field.
Certain types of gravitational effects can be shielded, but the first property makes such types of shielding rather bulky. For example, we can say that at Earth-Moon Lagrange points gravitational field of Earth is neutralized by the moon.

because there is no way that simple rearrangement of matter can neutralize the gravitational field. For anyone wondering, this appears to be true for antimatter as well.


Miss Understands asked: "is there a specific difference"

I don't know about the quantum woohoo, but from the relativistic perspective magnetic fields mediate forces while gravity is the geometry of spacetime.

Did Einsteins's attempt to geometrize electromagetism ever bear fruit?

@DavidTonhofer not sure of Einstein, but there's Kaluza-Klein theory that does this.

Arguably gravitational waves can be blocked by something that strongly interacts with gravity; the thing is such things would be extremely dense and not found except in very extreme circumstances like neutron stars and black holes.
G-waves in Einstein gravity are very hard to block without generating an equal and opposite wave, and generally pass through solid matter in linearized gravity, but in quantum representations (yet to be confirmed), gravity is an actual force produced by a graviton field such that $f^\mu=g\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}u^\nu u^\lambda$ for the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}$ and a coupling constant $g$, usually taken to be $-1$ (since then the geodesic acceleration equation is recovered). This mirrors the electromagnetic force equation $f^\mu=gF^\mu_\nu u^\nu$ for the electromagnetic tensor $F^\mu_\nu$ and another coupling constant; of course this seems to imply that G-waves can be blocked in a similar way to EM waves, but because gravity is so weak, producing something that can effectively block them would require producing an equivalent source of gravity which would be very dense and massive, which would of course be difficult.

So they could be blocked by interference just like em waves. Good. maybe we're getting somewhere. Except the rise and fall of a gravity wave as it passes through you doesn't have a negative phase that would cancel the positive phase. EM waves do. So you're saying it would be possible in theory to null a gravitational wave by putting it  out of phase with another g-wave?

Theoretically yeah. In linearized gravity you treat the g-wave as a perturbation $h$ to the metric like $g=\eta+h$ for the flat metric $\eta$; if you had a g-wave perturbation $h_1$ and an opposite-and-equal wave $h_2=-h_1$, then you'd get $g=\eta+h_1+h_2=\eta+h_1-h_1=\eta$ making spacetime overall flat.

The answer is because gravitons do not cause gravity directly, but rather they cause the warping of spacetime that becomes gravity.  So this warping of spacetime spreads out behind anything that might possibly shield the gravitons.
Imagine if you put a heater at one end of a pool of water, and then put a board in front of the heater.  While that board might stop the water directly behind it from being heated right away, eventually the heat from surrounding water would equalize with the water behind the board.

I would actually argue that gravitons do cause gravity if you model it as a spin-2 field theory. Massive particles would experience a force $f^\mu=\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda} u^\nu u^\lambda$ in alignment with the force produced by spin-1 fields $f^\mu=F^\mu_\nu u^\nu$. Quantum gravity and Einstein gravity are quite different in structure and phenomenology.

@controlgroup it's generally accepted that gravity is actually caused by time dilation which of course is part of the warping of SpaceTime. So we are not looking for a particle that attracts other particles in the way that a magnetic field does, but looking for a particle that causes this time dilation. This is the combination of quantum gravity and relativistic gravity that we are looking for.

I have not read any such thing, and I actively study relativity and quantum gravity. A spin-2 tensor field like a graviton produces exactly the same 4-force that gravity does. I would be very interested to see any papers that suggest that gravity is caused directly by time dilation.

@controlgroup You can find my full (peer reviewed and published) paper that provides the references here: https://www.pulsus.com/scholarly-articles/dilating-loop-relativity-an-examination-of-gluon-field-excitation-as-the-initiating-cause-of-time-dilation-gravity-and-d.pdf     In particular on the 4th page you'll see where Nobel Lauriat Kip Thorne said: " and this time warp produces gravity."   The rest of the paper discusses how virtual gluons take on the role of gravitons and cause this time dilation, as discussed in my answer above.

I actually think we've had this conversation before. Do you recall me noting that gluons are confined within hadrons and thus cannot play the role of a long-range force like gravity? I've read that paper already. You don't need a special particle to cause time dilation.

@controlgroup I am aware that gluons are confined. In a bar magnet, no electrons are lost and they do not lose power or drop to a lower orbit in the creation of the magnetic field surrounding the magnet. That magnetic field just exists. And it would stay there forever. It is for this reason that I don't think the confinement of gluons is an issue. The excitation of the gluon field surrounding the planet would just be there.  a simple comparison with the magnetic field surrounding a bar magnet makes this a reasonable statement.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
